# Elegant way to create a nested Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, linq

**I realized that I didn't give enough information for most people to read my mind and understand all my needs, so I changed this somewhat from the original.**

Say I've got a list of items of a class like this:

```
public class Thing
{
    int Foo;
    int Bar;
    string Baz;
}
```

And I want to categorize the Baz string based on the values of Foo, then Bar.  There will be at most one Thing for each possible combination of Foo and Bar values, but I'm not guaranteed to have a value for each one.  It may help to conceptualize it as cell information for a table: Foo is the row number, Bar is the column number, and Baz is the value to be found there, but there won't necessarily be a value present for every cell.

```
IEnumerable<Thing> things = GetThings();
List<int> foos = GetAllFoos();
List<int> bars = GetAllBars();
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>> dict = // what do I put here?
foreach(int foo in foos)
{
    // I may have code here to do something for each foo...
    foreach(int bar in bars)
    {
        // I may have code here to do something for each bar...
        if (dict.ContainsKey(foo) && dict[foo].ContainsKey(bar))
        {
            // I want to have O(1) lookups
            string baz = dict[foo][bar];
            // I may have code here to do something with the baz.
        }
    }
}
```

What's an easy, elegant way to generate the nested dictionary?  I've been using C# long enough that I'm getting used to finding simple, one-line solutions for all of the common stuff like this, but this one has me stumped.

Comment: What's the starting point? A list of Thing objects?

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far. I've updated the question to make it more clear.  It looks like some of you had the right idea already.  Once I test out your answers, I'll start upvoting and assign a winner.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here's a solution using Linq:

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>> dict = things
    .GroupBy(thing => thing.Foo)
    .ToDictionary(fooGroup => fooGroup.Key,
                  fooGroup => fooGroup.ToDictionary(thing => thing.Bar,
                                                    thing => thing.Baz));
```

Comment: Use "var dict ="

And you can use LINQ to collapse your multiple foreach statements:

var bazs = dict.SelectMany(topPair => topPair.Value.Values);
foreach(string baz in bazs)
{
  // ...
}

Comment: This appears to be the short, elegant solution I was looking for. The GroupBy/ToDictionary combo was what I was having trouble coming up with on my own.  Thank you.

Answer (score 23):

An elegant way would be to *not* create the dictionaries yourself but use LINQ `GroupBy` and `ToDictionary` to generate it for you.

```
var things = new[] {
    new Thing { Foo = 1, Bar = 2, Baz = "ONETWO!" },
    new Thing { Foo = 1, Bar = 3, Baz = "ONETHREE!" },
    new Thing { Foo = 1, Bar = 2, Baz = "ONETWO!" }
}.ToList();

var bazGroups = things
    .GroupBy(t => t.Foo)
    .ToDictionary(gFoo => gFoo.Key, gFoo => gFoo
        .GroupBy(t => t.Bar)
        .ToDictionary(gBar => gBar.Key, gBar => gBar.First().Baz));

Debug.Fail("Inspect the bazGroups variable.");
```

I assume that by categorizing `Baz` using `Foo` and `Bar` you mean that if two things have both `Foo` and `Bar` equals then their `Baz` value also be the same as well. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

You're basically group by the `Foo` property first...
then for each resulting group, you group on the `Bar` property...
then for each resulting group you take the first `Baz` value as the dictionary value.

If you noticed, the method names matched exactly what you are trying to do. :-)

---

**EDIT:** Here's another way using query comprehensions, they are longer but are quiet easier to read and grok:

```
var bazGroups =
    (from t1 in things
     group t1 by t1.Foo into gFoo
     select new
     {
         Key = gFoo.Key,
         Value = (from t2 in gFoo
                  group t2 by t2.Bar into gBar
                  select gBar)
                  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First().Baz)
     })
     .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Value);
```

Unfortunately, there are no query comprehension counterpart for ToDictionary so it's not as elegant as the lambda expressions.

...

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for completeness of your answer. I was tempted to mark this as *the* answer, but Mark's answer got more points for elegance by eliminating the need for the second `GroupBy` and the `First`.  (Matt, my sympathies, too. LINQ is pretty much the coolest thing in programming since OO, IMHO)

Comment: I tend to err on the side of readability and clear intentions. I think it's terse enough just using LINQ, no need to do all the clever tricks . Although, I agreed that dictionary trick one is nice :)

Comment: A question when I have multiple `things` to add how can I add to the existing dictionary

Comment: @User The snippets deal mostly with categorizing existing data. The resulting dictionary, though, doesn't prevent you from adding to it. Just do `dict["key1"]["key2"].Add("key3", "value")` as you would adding to any dictionary normally. Not sure if that's what you meant?

Comment: The accepted answer throws an exception (key already exists in dictionary). Granted, my use case differs from the question (the value of the second dict must be a list of DataRows). The second group by solved it for me.

Answer (score 5):

Define your own custom generic `NestedDictionary` class

```
public class NestedDictionary<K1, K2, V>: 
     Dictionary<K1, Dictionary<K2, V>> {}
```

then in your code you write

```
NestedDictionary<int, int, string> dict = 
       new NestedDictionary<int, int, string> ();
```

if you use the int, int, string one a lot, define a custom class for that too..

```
   public class NestedIntStringDictionary: 
        NestedDictionary<int, int, string> {}
```

and then write:

```
  NestedIntStringDictionary dict = 
          new NestedIntStringDictionary();
```

EDIT: To add capability to construct specific instance from provided List of items:

```
   public class NestedIntStringDictionary: 
        NestedDictionary<int, int, string> 
   {
        public NestedIntStringDictionary(IEnumerable<> items)
        {
            foreach(Thing t in items)
            {
                Dictionary<int, string> innrDict = 
                       ContainsKey(t.Foo)? this[t.Foo]: 
                           new Dictionary<int, string> (); 
                if (innrDict.ContainsKey(t.Bar))
                   throw new ArgumentException(
                        string.Format(
                          "key value: {0} is already in dictionary", t.Bar));
                else innrDict.Add(t.Bar, t.Baz);
            }
        }
   }
```

and then write:

```
  NestedIntStringDictionary dict = 
       new NestedIntStringDictionary(GetThings());
```

Comment: What would the accessor look like?

Comment: How does this help me to elegantly build a nested dictionary from the data I've been given?

Comment: Sorry, I answered original question, which did not make this point clear... Edited my answer to show you, explicitly, how to do that...

Answer (score 3):

Another approach would be to key your dictionary using an anonymous type based on both the Foo and Bar values.

```
var things = new List<Thing>
                 {
                     new Thing {Foo = 3, Bar = 4, Baz = "quick"},
                     new Thing {Foo = 3, Bar = 8, Baz = "brown"},
                     new Thing {Foo = 6, Bar = 4, Baz = "fox"},
                     new Thing {Foo = 6, Bar = 8, Baz = "jumps"}
                 };
var dict = things.ToDictionary(thing => new {thing.Foo, thing.Bar},
                               thing => thing.Baz);
var baz = dict[new {Foo = 3, Bar = 4}];
```

This effectively flattens your hierarchy into a single dictionary.
Note that this dictionary cannot be exposed externally since it is based on an anonymous type.

If the Foo and Bar value combination isn't unique in your original collection, then you would need to group them first.

```
var dict = things
    .GroupBy(thing => new {thing.Foo, thing.Bar})
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key,
                  group => group.Select(thing => thing.Baz));
var bazes = dict[new {Foo = 3, Bar = 4}];
foreach (var baz in bazes)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your taking the time to come up with such a complete answer, and I can understand why you came up with this solution based on how I originally worded the question, but it doesn't actually do what I need it to.

Comment: it does what i need it to do :)

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use a [KeyedCollection](http://www.csharp411.com/keyedcollection-dictionary-for-values-with-embedded-keys/) where you define:

```
class ThingCollection
    : KeyedCollection<Dictionary<int,int>,Employee>
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: It isn't immediately obvious to me how this would solve my problem. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

Use BeanMap's two key Map class. There is also a 3 key map, and it is quite extensible in case you need n keys.

http://beanmap.codeplex.com/

Your solution would then look like:

```
class Thing
{
  public int Foo { get; set; }
  public int Bar { get; set; }
  public string Baz { get; set; }
}

[TestMethod]
public void ListToMapTest()
{
  var things = new List<Thing>
             {
                 new Thing {Foo = 3, Bar = 3, Baz = "quick"},
                 new Thing {Foo = 3, Bar = 4, Baz = "brown"},
                 new Thing {Foo = 6, Bar = 3, Baz = "fox"},
                 new Thing {Foo = 6, Bar = 4, Baz = "jumps"}
             };

  var thingMap = Map<int, int, string>.From(things, t => t.Foo, t => t.Bar, t => t.Baz);

  Assert.IsTrue(thingMap.ContainsKey(3, 4));
  Assert.AreEqual("brown", thingMap[3, 4]);

  thingMap.DefaultValue = string.Empty;
  Assert.AreEqual("brown", thingMap[3, 4]);
  Assert.AreEqual(string.Empty, thingMap[3, 6]);

  thingMap.DefaultGeneration = (k1, k2) => (k1.ToString() + k2.ToString());

  Assert.IsFalse(thingMap.ContainsKey(3, 6));
  Assert.AreEqual("36", thingMap[3, 6]);
  Assert.IsTrue(thingMap.ContainsKey(3, 6));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest approach would be to use the LINQ extension methods. Obviously I haven't tested this code for performace.

```
var items = new[] {
  new Thing { Foo = 1, Bar = 3, Baz = "a" },
  new Thing { Foo = 1, Bar = 3, Baz = "b" },
  new Thing { Foo = 1, Bar = 4, Baz = "c" },
  new Thing { Foo = 2, Bar = 4, Baz = "d" },
  new Thing { Foo = 2, Bar = 5, Baz = "e" },
  new Thing { Foo = 2, Bar = 5, Baz = "f" }
};

var q = items
  .ToLookup(i => i.Foo) // first key
  .ToDictionary(
    i => i.Key, 
    i => i.ToLookup(
      j => j.Bar,       // second key
      j => j.Baz));     // value

foreach (var foo in q) {
  Console.WriteLine("{0}: ", foo.Key);
  foreach (var bar in foo.Value) {
    Console.WriteLine("  {0}: ", bar.Key);
    foreach (var baz in bar) {
      Console.WriteLine("    {0}", baz.ToUpper());
    }
  }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

```
1:
  3:
    A
    B
  4:
    C
2:
  4:
    D
  5:
    E
    F
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>> nestedDictionary = 
            new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>>();
```

Comment: You didn't quite understand the gist of my question. I'm looking for a linq statement or something that would allow me to populate the dictionary from an existing list, not simply instantiate it.