# Convert XML tree to nested Dictionary

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, xml-parsing

I'd like to convert a XML file to a Dictionary. The XML file is strucured as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Definitions>   
    <Organization ID="201">
        <Department Name="Facility">
            <Employees>200</Employees>
            <Building>3</Building>
            <Obj>classnameA</Obj>
        </Department>
        <Department Name="IT">
            <Employees>12</Employees>
            <Building>2</Building>
            <Obj>classnameB</Obj>
        </Department>
    </Organization> 
</Definitions>
```

I'd like to use a nested dictionary, which can be conceptualized as a table such that "Department" is the row number, "Organization" is the column number, and "Employees", "Building", and "Obj" are the values to be found there. Therefore, I create the following class (with the help of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918742/elegant-way-to-create-a-nested-dictionary-in-c-sharp)):

```
public class NestedDictionary<K1, K2, V> :
 Dictionary<K1, Dictionary<K2, V>> { }
```

Then, I need to convert the content of my XML file to *NestedDictionary* by iterating though the tree. How can I add the three attributes "Employees", "Building", and "Obj" to the my Dictionary?

```
private static void XmlToDict(XmlNode definitions)
{
    NestedDictionary<int, string, string> dictionary = new NestedDictionary<int, string, string>();

    foreach (XmlNode idNode in definitions)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode nameNode in idNode)
        {
            // The following line does not work
            dictionary.Add(idNode.Name, nameNode.Name, nameNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to be able to retrieve data like this: `Definitions[201]["Facility"]["Employees"]`?

Comment: "does not work" doesn't give us enough information. Does `NestedDictionary` have an `Add(K1, K2, V)` method?

Comment: NestedDictionary does not have an Add method, yet. It doesn't matter how I can retrieve the data. `Definitions[201]["Facility"]["Employees"]` would be great. `Definitions[201]["Facility"].Employees` would also be great...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This LINQ expression will convert your XML data in to a nested dictionary. It assumes that `element` is of type `XDocument` or `XElement` from the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace.

```
var element = XElement.Parse(yourXML);
var result = element.Descendants("Organization")
                .Select(org => new {
                    ID = org.Attribute("ID").Value,
                    Departments = org.Descendants("Department")
                    .Select(dept => new {
                        Name = dept.Attribute("Name").Value,
                        Employees = int.Parse(dept.Element("Employees").Value),
                        Building = dept.Element("Building").Value,
                        Obj = dept.Element("Obj").Value
                    })
                })
                .ToDictionary(
                    org => int.Parse(org.ID),
                    org => org.Departments.ToDictionary(dept => dept.Name));
```

result becomes a dictionary of `<int, Dictionary<string, anonymous_type>>`. Of course, if you don't wish to have an anonymous type, you can declare your own `Department` class:

```
public class Department
{
    public int Building { get; set; }
    public int Employees { get; set; }
    public string Obj { get; set; }
}
```

and call `new Department { ... }` instead of the anonymous `new { ... }` shown above. That expression will instead product a dictionary of type `<int, Dictionary<string, Department>>`

**Without using LINQ**:

```
    public class XmlConverter
    {
        public static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, Department>> Convert(XmlDocument xdoc)
        {
            Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, Department>> result = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, Department>>();

            foreach (XmlNode org in xdoc.SelectNodes("Definitions/Organization")) {
                int orgId = int.Parse(org.SelectSingleNode("@ID").Value);
                result.Add(orgId, GetDepartments(org));
            }

            return result;
        }

        private static Dictionary<string, Department> GetDepartments(XmlNode org)
        {
            Dictionary<string, Department> result = new Dictionary<string, Department>();

            foreach (XmlNode dept in org.SelectNodes("Department")) {
                string deptName = dept.SelectSingleNode("@Name").Value;
                Department d = new Department();

                d.Employees = int.Parse(dept.SelectSingleNode("Employees/text()").Value);
                d.Building = int.Parse(dept.SelectSingleNode("Building/text()").Value);
                d.Obj = dept.SelectSingleNode("Obj/text()").Value;

                result.Add(deptName, d);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

We represent an Organization as a `Dictionary<string, Department>` whose keys are department names and values are department objects.

The entire tree is represented as a `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, Department>>` whose keys are organization IDs, and values are department dictionaries.

Comment: I forgot to tell: For some reason I have to use .NET 2.0. So, I cannot use [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.linq%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Well. That's cute. I'll get back to you shortly if someone hasn't beaten me to it.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I am just wondering how the accessor might look like?

Comment: Can you further explain your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use paste XML as C# Classes in Microsoft Visual Studio. You can use generated class to describe your dictionary, tuple, or what your needs are, name of the properties/objects will be exactly as your Xml is file is built.
Using:

```
1. Visual Studio 2012 IDE you can convert XML document into C# classes as a Serializable type.
```

OR

```
2. In .NET framework 4.5 there you have: Menu -> Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste Xml as Classes.
```

This feature saved me for a lot of work, I used before this:

Xsd.exe can be found in the [InstallDrive]:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET [2003]\SDK[v1.1]\bin directory. 
The utility's default output language for source is C# producing an XSD, and using that XSD to produce a standard C# class and finally a strongly typed DataSet.

Open the command prompt and type xsd.exe /? to see all the commads and switch options for the utility.

How it works?

> ```
> Locate the Command Prompt from your version of visual studio:
> 1.    Check if xsd.exe exist (type xsd.exe) if true a list of commads will be displayed. 
> 2.    Navigate to your work folder.  (cd, cd..)
> 3.    Create your xml file MyFile.xml
> 4.    Run the transformation from xml to xsd with xsd.exe MyFile.xml
> 5.    Next create MyFile.cs wit command xsd.exe MyFile.xsd /c
> In the folder is now created a file .cs with the C# class ready to read from xml.
> ```

Comment: I need to do that in Unity3d, which uses a .NET 2.0 like mono implementation. However, I will try to set it up in VS and than copy the files to my Unity Folder. I hope it will work. Thank you!